# How to show datepicker only when a option is selected?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, datepicker

I am using react-datepicker and have a select with 4 options, I need to show the calendar only when option number 3 is selected. Here's the code I have so far.

```js
const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date())
```

```html
 <div className="input-block">
   <label htmlFor="status">Status</label>
   <select id="status" name="status" required>
     <option value="1">Aguardando Disponibilidade</option>
     <option value="2">Aguardando Agendamento</option>
     <option value="3">Ativação Agendada</option>
     <option value="4">Ativação Efetuada</option>
   </select>

   <div className="calendar">
     <DatePicker
       className="calendar-input"
       selected={startDate}
       onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
       showTimeSelect
       timeFormat="HH:mm"
       dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm "
      />
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, please post all the component's code.

Comment: I edited the code, but the those are the only components from datepicker

Comment: you can hook up the select value with the component's state. then conditionally render the datepicker if you have the correct state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const YourComp = () => {
  const [selectedValue, updateSelectedValue] = useState();
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date())

  const onSelectChange = ({ target: { value } }) => updateSelectedValue(value);

  return (
    <div className="input-block">
     <label htmlFor="status">Status</label>
     <select
      id="status"
      name="status"
      required
      onChange={onSelectChange}
     >
       <option value="1">Aguardando Disponibilidade</option>
       <option value="2">Aguardando Agendamento</option>
       <option value="3">Ativação Agendada</option>
       <option value="4">Ativação Efetuada</option>
     </select>
   {
     selectedValue === '3'
     ? (
      <div className="calendar">
        <DatePicker
         className="calendar-input"
         selected={startDate}
         onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
         showTimeSelect
         timeFormat="HH:mm"
         dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm "
        />
      </div>
     )
     : null
   }
</div>
  )
}
```

The above mentioned code should resolve your issue. The idea is to put a conditional check to render DatePicker component. [React Official Doc - Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)